# beautifulsoup filter id in class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

im trying to print the amount of rap the player has:
my html elements: `<h5 class="card-title mb-1 text-light text-truncate stat-data" id="player_rap">6,751</h5>`
im trying to extract 6,751, i tried:

````
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(f"https://www.rolimons.com/player/{id}").content, 'html.parser')
    value = soup.find("h5", {"class": "card-title mb-1 text-light text-truncate stat-data", "id":"player_value"})
    print(value)```
````

Comment: The player_value is rendered dynamically by JS, so bs4 won't see it.

Comment: can you give me a valid id?

Comment: Try this link `https://www.rolimons.com/api/playerassets/{id}` you will get a json with all the player info

Comment: thanks but i get this error
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

when i try: def getvalue(id):
    r = requests.get(f"https://www.rolimons.com/api/playerassets/{id}")
    print(r.json())

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started when it comes to player's assets and badges. However, as of now, I've not pinned down the request responsible for player's profile. I'll update the answer if I find out more.

Here the code to fetch the JSON.

```
import requests

headers = {
    "authority": "www.rolimons.com",
    "method": "GET",
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
}


def build_uaid_urls(player_assets: dict) -> list:
    uaids = []
    for id_container in player_assets.values():
        for _id in id_container:
            uaids.append(f"https://www.rolimons.com/uaid/{_id}")
    return uaids


def build_item_urls(player_assets: dict) -> list:
    return [
        f"https://www.rolimons.com/item/{_id}" for _id in player_assets.keys()
    ]


url = "https://www.rolimons.com/api/playerassets/2"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

assets = r["playerAssets"]
print(assets)

print(build_uaid_urls(assets))
print(build_item_urls(assets))
```

This, for example, prints out player's assets. Each key holds a list with the UAID page. If there's more than 1 item in the list, this means that the player owns copies.

```
{'1533893': [16601743], '4765718': [13170198], '5785985': [16601740], '5786026': [16601741], '5786047': [16601742], '24826853': [330312294, 330312295], '24830979': [330312298], '27345567': [330312296], '31149956': [330312280, 330312284], '31151864': [330312285], '31157811': [330312290, 330312299, 330312302]}
```

You can use these values to build links to all the assets with `build_uaid_urls()` that outputs:

```
https://www.rolimons.com/uaid/16601743
https://www.rolimons.com/uaid/13170198
https://www.rolimons.com/uaid/16601740
https://www.rolimons.com/uaid/16601741
...
```

And each key from the player's assets is an id to the item's page. These also can be easily build (and then scraped).

Output:

```
['https://www.rolimons.com/item/1533893', 'https://www.rolimons.com/item/4765718', 'https://www.rolimons.com/item/5785985', 'https://www.rolimons.com/item/5786026', 'https://www.rolimons.com/item/5786047', 'https://www.rolimons.com/item/24826853', 'https://www.rolimons.com/item/24830979', 'https://www.rolimons.com/item/27345567', 'https://www.rolimons.com/item/31149956', 'https://www.rolimons.com/item/31151864', 'https://www.rolimons.com/item/31157811']
```

Answer (score -1):

Try searching for solely the ID.

```
value = soup.find("h5", {"id": "player_value"})
```

Comment: that prints ```<h5 class="card-title mb-1 text-light text-truncate stat-data player_stat_spinner" id="player_value"> </h5>```

Comment: add ```get_text()``` to the end of it

Comment: prints nothing just a empty space